# JAXB - Namespace is not accepted

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have in entry some XML with theses namespaces :

```
xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'
```

Unfortunately, for what I know, the

```
xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'
```

Launch an error if I want to create classes with JAXB. I tried to change the namespace, but then when I want to unmarshall, JAXB said that he expect another namespace that he founds.

So I'm trying to find a solution to avoid this problem, and if possible doesn't want to dynamically change my namespaces...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you marshall something, then change the namespace, then tried to unmarshal the same file you marshalled with the old namespace?

Comment: I ask again: Was the flow of your actions like this: **1,** write a file with old namespace(s) **2,** change namespace used in code **3,** read old file. Please answer with a straight **yes** or **no**, what you answered was not even in connection with what I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I update my question to make it more clear (i wish). And no, the files in entry are not generated by myself.

Comment: And when I say "I tried to change the namespace", I mean in the XSD I used to create the JAXB Classes. Hope it's more clear.

Comment: Do you try to run XJC to produce JAXB 2 Java classes from XML Schema (XSD) ?

Comment: Yes I did, but when I tried with the following namespace : xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema' JAXB launch an error.